# Why don't I have a /usr/local on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, hadoop

I followed [a tutorial to install hadoop](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04). I tried to move the folder to `/usr/local/`:

```
sudo mv hadoop-2.9* /usr/local/hadoop
```

but it answered me :

```
mv: target '/usr/local/hadoop' is not a directory
```

Isn't it the appropriate place for locally installed software ?

Comment: The thing is, /usr/local, usr/local/, and ~/usr/local/ are three different locations. Which one do you want?

Comment: @mikewhatever Hey! Thanks for the insight ! I would live to move it into  into ̀/usr/local` as written in the tutorial

Comment: @mikewhatever "appropriate place for locally installed software"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked tutorial has shows the command as:

```
sudo mv hadoop-2.7.3 /usr/local/hadoop`
```

There should be no tilde `~` before the file path. Tilde is expanded as your user's home directory, in this case `/home/mike/`, so you're trying to create `/home/mike/usr/local/hadoop` rather than `/usr/local/hadoop`

The following command should work:

```
sudo mv hadoop-2.9* /usr/local/hadoop
```

Beware that if you have more than one match for `hadoop-2.9*` the `mv` command will fail with a complaint about too many arguments for the command.